# how to start an activity from a custom component & pass data in between?

Tags: android

I have created a component for table row and added in to another activity.it's working fine.That table row has a button and some textviews.Now i want to pass values and start another activity when i am pressing this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//from where you have send data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("yourKey","yourvalue");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```

// on receiving activity
//onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSatet);

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String a = bundle.getString("yourkey")
```

and as such populate your data

i hope this will help you.